# How can I skip the first page in this script? GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script, tell me how to make sure that the first page is not affected? Thank you very much

```js
    function onOpen() {
           var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
           var menubuttons = [ {name: "Сleaning" , functionName: "CleanAllSheets"},];
           ss.addMenu("Сleaning", (menubuttons));
    }                          
    
    function CleanAllSheets() { 
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          ss.getSheets().forEach((sheet) => {CleanSheet(sheet);})
    
    }                     
    
    function CleanSheet(sheet) {
          sheet.getRange('A2:Z100').clearContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice` to shorten the array of sheets to be deleted:

```
function onOpen() {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var menubuttons = [ {name: "Сleaning" , functionName: "CleanAllSheets"},];
       ss.addMenu("Сleaning", (menubuttons));
}                          

function CleanAllSheets() { 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var l = ss.getSheets().length;
      ss.getSheets().slice(1,l).forEach((sheet) => {CleanSheet(sheet);})

}                     

function CleanSheet(sheet) {
      sheet.getRange('A2:Z100').clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the index in your forEach and skip if zero.

```
ss.getSheets().forEach((sheet, i) => { if (i != 0) CleanSheet(sheet); })
```